# Using the redis ruby gem, how do I clear a set of keys from redis matching a pattern?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, heroku, redis

I'm using Redis with Ruby on Rails.

I want to delete an entire set of keys from redis in a single operation if I can. I'm using the `redis.rb` gem. The keys are from entries generated from my test environment and all contain the string ':test:' in them.

Thanks -

Comment: This thread in the redis-db mailing list discusses ways to delete large number of keys - https://groups.google.com/d/topic/redis-db/IA-bu0RRQog/discussion

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK client.del "some_key" will try to erase somekey*